# How to call controller method on html load in angular.js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a method in an AngularJS controller for converting a plain string into a globalized string based on language selected on page.

This controller method internally calls an Angular service method which calls mvc controller method.

**Controller method:**

```
$scope.getGlobalizedText = function(cultureId, key) {
    DataServiceDeviceSummary.getGlobalizedText(cultureId, key).success(function (message) {
        $scope.DeviceName = message;
            console.log(message);
        }).
        error(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

I want to call this method at many places like for populating the label or for populating header value of the html table.

I am calling this method in the following way:

```
<th colspan="2">
    <a data-order="Ascending">{{getGlobalizedText(2, 'DeviceName')}}</a>
</th>
```

I am facing two problems while calling controller method like this:

1. This method is being called infinitely given the fact that method is getting passed successfully and returning correct result.
2. The return value is not populating in hyperlink.

I am not sure why is this happening. Also I can not call this method on some button `click` event or any similar event because this may need to get called many times whenever I load the page, or some new text gets populated in the html.

Comment: Any call in `{{}}` interpolation get evaluated multiple times during Angular digest cycle. Secondly your function does not return any data, that get bound in the interpolation. Maybe you meant `{{DeviceName}}`

Comment: Is there any alternative to call this method for single time for loading texts on label, headers and other places?

Comment: You can look at `run` method which is similar to `config` method on module. Called once the module is initialize. You should have a service that loads the localized content into a array\object that can be shared across the app. Also look at angular-translate.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this method on document ready as the following :

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    /* considering $scope.getGlobalizedText method is defined already */
    $scope.getGlobalizedText(2, 'DeviceName');
});
```

Also call this method whenever some new text gets populated in the html.